# Using dplyr functions within another function

Tags: r, dplyr

I've been struggling with this issue which is quite similar to [a question raised here before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29119052/r-using-dplyr-inside-a-function-exception-in-evalexpr-envir-enclos-unknow). Somehow I can't translate the solution given in that question to my own problem.

I start off with making an example data frame:

```
test.df <- data.frame(col1 = rep(c('a','b'), each=5), col2 = runif(10))
str(test.df)
```

The following function should create a new data frame with the mean of a "statvar" based on groups of a "groupvar".

```
test.f <- function(df, groupvar, statvar) {
  df %>% 
    group_by_(groupvar) %>% 
    select_(statvar) %>%
    summarise_(
      avg = ~mean(statvar, na.rm = TRUE)
    )
} 

test.f(df = test.df,
       groupvar = "col1",
       statvar = "col2")
```

What I would like this to return is a data frame with 2 calculated averages (one for all a values in col1 and one for all b values in col1). Instead I get this:

```
  col1 avg
1    a  NA
2    b  NA
Warning messages:
1: In mean.default("col2", na.rm = TRUE) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: In mean.default("col2", na.rm = TRUE) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

I find this strange cause I'm pretty sure col2 is numeric:

```
str(test.df)
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ col1: Factor w/ 2 levels "a","b": 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2
 $ col2: num  0.4269 0.1928 0.7766 0.0865 0.1798 ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(lazyeval)
library(dplyr)

test.f <- function(df, groupvar, statvar) {
  test.df %>% 
    group_by_(groupvar) %>% 
    select_(statvar) %>%
    summarise_(
      avg = (~mean(statvar, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
        interp(statvar = as.name(statvar))
    )
} 

test.f(df = test.df,
       groupvar = "col1",
       statvar = "col2")
```

Your issue is that "col2" is being substituted for statvar, and the `mean("col2")` is undefined

Comment: This works perfectly, many thanks. So interp() basically says "R, you should see this as a variable and not as a character string"? Yet I'm still a bit puzzled why avg is connected to interp() with the piping symbol %>%.

Comment: @1053Inator, You could write it as `avg = interp(~mean(statvar, na.rm = TRUE), statvar = as.name(statvar))` without piping

Comment: interp takes the expresion `~mean(statvar, na.rm = TRUE)` and replaces every time it sees the word statvar with the result of as.name(statvar), i.e., col2. So the expression is transformed to `~mean(col2, na.rm = TRUE)`

Answer (score 0):

With the soon to be released dplyr `0.6.0`, new functionality can help. The new function is `UQ()`, it unquotes what has been quoted. You are entering `statvar` as a string like `"col1"`. dplyr has alternate functions that can evaluate regularly as in `group_by_` and `select_`. But for `summarise_` the alteration of the string can be ugly as in the above answer. We can now use the regular `summarise` function and unquote the quoted variable name. For more help on what 'unquote the quoted' means, [see this vignette](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html). For now [the developer's version](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr) has it.

```
library(dplyr)
test.df <- data.frame(col1 = rep(c('a','b'), each=5), col2 = runif(10))
test.f <- function(df, groupvar, statvar) {
  q_statvar <- as.name(statvar)
  df %>% 
    group_by_(groupvar) %>% 
    select_(statvar) %>%
    summarise(
      avg = mean(!!q_statvar, na.rm = TRUE)
    )
} 

test.f(df = test.df,
       groupvar = "col1",
       statvar = "col2")
# # A tibble: 2 × 2
#     col1       avg
#   <fctr>     <dbl>
# 1      a 0.6473072
# 2      b 0.4282954
```