# Cross comparison of data frames in R

Tags: r

I have to compare two people datasets between each other.

Let's say i have a data frame with few columns `a =`.

```
    ID  |     Name        |      Gender      |  Country   
   ——————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
    1   | Mattias Adams   |        M         |    UK           
    2   | James Alan      |        M         |    Canada
    3   | Dana Benton     |        F         |    USA
    4   | Ella Collins    |        F         |    USA
```

And `b =`

```
    ID  | First_Name | Last_name  | Third_name |  Whole_name       |  Gender   
————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
    1   |    Gary    |  Cole      |    Allan   | Gary Allan Cole   |    M
    2   |    Dana    |  Benton    |    NA      | Dana Benton       |    F
    3   |    Lena    |  Jamison   |    Anne    | Lena Anne Jamison |    F        
    4   |    Matt    |  King      |    NA      | Matt King         |    M
```

Data frame `a` is the bigger one contains around 100,000 rows while `b` contains less than 1,000.

The goal is to use the data in `b` to find matching records in `a`. So that the whole row in `a` is returned if there is a match.

I want to try two ways. First to find exact matches from `b$"Whole_name"` in `a$"Name"`.

**Exact matching:**

```
    eue_wn <- as.character(b$"Whole_name")
    eue_wn_match <- a[which(as.character(a$"Name") %in% eue_wn),]
        if (nrow(eue_wn_match) == 0) {
             eue_wn_match <- "No matches"
        }
```

Output of `eue_wn_matc` in this case would be:

```
    ID  |     Name        |      Gender      |  Country   
   —————————————————————————————————————————————————————————— 
    3   | Dana Benton     |        F         |    USA
```

**Pattern matching:**

```
    eup_ln <- paste(as.character(b$"Last_name"), collapse = "|")
    eup_fn <- paste(as.character(b$"First_Name"), collapse = "|")
    eup_tn <- paste(as.character(b$"Third_name"), collapse = "|")

    eup_match <- a[which(grepl(eup_ln, as.character(a$"Name"), ignore.case = TRUE)),]         #First filter (last name)
    if (nrow(eup_match) == 0) {
        eup_match <- "No matches"
    } 
    if (nrow(eup_match) > 0) {
        eup_match2 <- eup_match[which(grepl(eup_fn, as.character(eup_match$"Name"), ignore.case = TRUE)),]     #Second filter (first name)
          if (nrow(eup_match2) == 0 ) {
            eup_match2 <- "No matches"
          }
    }

    if (nrow(eup_match2) > 0) {
      eup_match3 <- eup_match2[which(grepl(eup_tn, as.character(eup_match2$"Name"), ignore.case = TRUE)),]     #Third filter (third_name)
      if (nrow(eup_match3) == 0 ) {
        eup_match3 <- "No matches"
      }
    }
```

So in this process the matching takes place in 3 stages. 
First `eup_match` is the result of finding the last name. Than it takes that result and looks for second match  which is the first name name results `eup_match2` shows record that matches both conditions. Finally the last result is taken and is being matched also with the third name `eup_match3`

in this case the result of all three of them is the same:

```
    ID  |     Name        |      Gender      |  Country   
   —————————————————————————————————————————————————————————— 
    3   | Dana Benton     |        F         |    USA
```

And that is incorrect. Only `eup_match` and `eup_match2` should have that output. Since in the first stage we were matching  `Dana Benton(a)`  and `Dana(b)` 
In the next stage the match was  `Dana Benton(a)`  and `Benton (b)`. And since she does not have a third name it is impossible to match her with third name. 
The problem is in:

```
eup_tn <- paste(as.character(b$"Third_name"), collapse = "|")
```

The output off this is :

```
"Allan|NA|Anne|NA"
```

Because the NA was converted to character the function was able to find pattern in a and b. In this particular case  `Dana Benson (a`) and `NA (b)`

Any idea on how to correct that ?

Another question is related to the output. Is there any way to output both results from `a` and `b`

Example:  if we are only matching the `a$Name` with `b$First_Name` by patterns the result would be

```
ID  |     Name        |      Gender      |  Country   | Match | Match ID
———————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
1   | Mattias Adams   |        M         |    UK      | Matt  |    4 
3   | Dana Benton     |        F         |    USA     | Dana  |    2
```

So that the first 4 columns are from the data set `a` and the last two from `b`
  Columns `Match | Match ID` would show based on what were the records in `b` matched.

The desired output for the test example given would be:

```
    ID  |     Name        |      Gender      |  Country   
   —————————————————————————————————————————————————————————— 
    3   | Dana Benton     |        F         |    USA
```

Sorry for the long post. I tried to make it as clear as possible. If anyone would like to recreate this, xlsx files `a` and `b` as well as the r code can be found here: [MyDropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/eknaizbqoem2x0s/AACff8D2pfhrwkDVLh7PJScsa?dl=0)

If anyone has other suggestions on how to approach this topic is welcome to present them. Thank you for the help.

Comment: What is your expected result of this function?

Comment: I'm sorry if it was not clear enough. Basicly we need to compare some lists of people (in this example df `b`) against our own list of clients (df `a`) .  The data in the lists of people we need to compare is not high quality and the most accurate fields are the name fields (`First_name`, `Last_name`, `Third_name` and  `Whole_name` )

Comment: If you don’t always have a Third Name, I would look into `fuzzyjoin::stringdist_inner_join()` on a combination of First_Name & Last_Name, which is an approach that merges the ones that I proposed.

Comment: And: what would be the **exact expected result** for a perfect match-function for the data that you gave?

Comment: Thank you for your help and suggestions. I owe you a beer :) . That is right the `Third_name` column has a lot of empty cells. 

The perfect result for pattern searching would be: if I  serach in `a` for people listed in `b`  the output would contain data from the person in `a` (i.e. our client)  and information  based on which record in `b` was he matched (the string that matched and the id number that is in the first column of the same record is enought).

Comment: No problem, that’s what SO is for. I mean: could you post in your original post the exact output that you would expect from the data that you gave? I mean: is it only Dana? Or also, e.g., Matt?

Comment: It that case the desired output would be something like  first the whole row from `a`   and than the match from `b` alongside the id number of the match ... So basically `3   | Dana Benton     |        F         |    USA     | Dana  |    2`

Comment: Great, thank you. This is information that you should append to the original post. I edited my solution and it matches closely what you wanted to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Approach #1: Exact match

Why not something along the lines of

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
a <- a %>%
    # Extract first and last names into new variables
    mutate(First_Name = str_extract(Name, "^[A-z]+"),
           Last_Name = str_extract(Name, "[A-z]+$"),)

# Inner Join by first and last name.
# Add a suffix to be able to distinguish the origin of columns.
b %>% inner_join(a, by = c("First_Name", "Last_Name"), suffix = c(".b", ".a")) %>%
    # Select the columns you want to see.
    # Note that only the colums that have an ambiguous name have a suffix.
    select(ID.a, Name, Gender.a, Country, First_Name, Last_Name, ID.b)
```

Works great if you are looking for exact matches only. If you like, you can also extract the middle name from a string via `str_extract(string, "[^A-z]+[A-z]+[^A-z$]")`.

Result:

```
  ID.a        Name Gender.a Country First_Name Last_Name ID.b
1    3 Dana Benton        F     USA       Dana    Benton    2
```

---

### Approach #2: Word distance (Jaro-Winkler)

Expanding from [this great post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29103325):

```
library(RecordLinkage)
library(dplyr)

lookup <- expand.grid(target = a$Name, source = b$Whole_Name, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

lookup %>% group_by(target) %>%
    mutate(match_score = jarowinkler(target, source)) %>%
    summarise(match = match_score[which.max(match_score)], matched_to = ref[which.max(match_score)]) %>%
    inner_join(b, c("matched_to" = "Whole_Name"))
```

Anything above .8 or .9 should be a good match. Still not perfect. You could try to match first and last name separately, if your data is clean.

Result:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 8
  target        match matched_to         ID First_Name Last_Name Third_Name Gender
  <chr>         <dbl> <chr>           <dbl> <chr>      <chr>     <chr>      <chr> 
1 Dana Benton   1     Dana Benton         2 Dana       Benton    NA         F     
2 Ella Collins  0.593 Matt King           4 Matt       King      NA         M     
3 James Alan    0.667 Gary Allan Cole     1 Gary       Cole      Allan      M     
4 Mattias Adams 0.792 Matt King           4 Matt       King      NA         M
```

---

### Approach #3: Word distance (Levenshtein)

Same as above, just using the Levenshtein distance and `which.min()`

```
library(RecordLinkage)
library(dplyr)


lookup <- expand.grid(target = a$Name, source = b$Whole_Name, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

lookup %>% group_by(target) %>%
    mutate(match_score = levenshteinDist(target, source)) %>%
    summarise(match = match_score[which.min(match_score)], matched_to = ref[which.min(match_score)]) %>%
    inner_join(b, c("matched_to" = "Whole_Name"))
```

As expected, this gives a poorer performance than JW.

Result:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 8
  target        match matched_to     ID First_Name Last_Name Third_Name Gender
  <chr>         <int> <chr>       <dbl> <chr>      <chr>     <chr>      <chr> 
1 Dana Benton       0 Dana Benton     2 Dana       Benton    NA         F     
2 Ella Collins      9 Dana Benton     2 Dana       Benton    NA         F     
3 James Alan        8 Matt King       4 Matt       King      NA         M     
4 Mattias Adams     8 Matt King       4 Matt       King      NA         M
```

---

### Data

```
a <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4), Name = c("Mattias Adams", "James Alan", "Dana Benton", "Ella Collins"), Gender = c("M", "M", "F", "F"), Country = c("UK", "Canada", "USA", "USA")), .Names = c("ID", "Name", "Gender", "Country"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
b <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4), First_Name = c("Gary", "Dana", "Lena", "Matt"), Last_name = c("Cole", "Benton", "Jamison", "King"), Third_Name = c("Allan", "NA", "Anne", "NA"), Whole_name = c("Gary Allan Cole", "Dana Benton", "Lena Anne Jamison", "Matt King"), Gender = c("M", "F", "F", "M")), .Names = c("ID", "First_Name", "Last_Name", "Third_Name", "Whole_Name", "Gender"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid the false matches to `NA`, don't include it in the pattern.  Use this instead:

```
eup_tn <- paste(na.omit(as.character(b$"Third_name")), collapse = "|")
```

As to your second question:  that's done using the `merge()` function in base R, or one of the replacements for it in `?dplyr::join`, probably `inner_join()`.